# How to export Store Credit Balances from 1.14 to CSV

Tags: customer-account, enterprise-1.14, store-credit, database-export

I'm migrating a Magento EE 1.14 store to another platform and can't figure out how to export customer store credit balances to a data file.

Anyone know where to find the current credit balance for each customer in the database? I see the credit memos, etc. but I don't see where the current balance is stored. Is it stored? or is it recalculated each time that it's needed? That seems like an odd way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Should have looked harder...

The customer store credit balances are stored in the table `enterprise_customerbalance`.

Can JOIN `enterprise_customerbalance.customer_id` = `customer_entity.entity.id` to get a CSV for export.